# MySQL query - indentiyfing data using URL names where data is organised into a hierachy

Tags: mysql, sql, database, url, permalinks

I have a mysql table called content which stores content data for a content management system.

NOTE: all content is organised into a hierachy using a parent id column.

```
+----+------------+-----------------+--------+
| id | slug       | content_type_id | parent |
+----+------------+-----------------+--------+
|  1 | portfolio  |               5 |      0 |
|  2 | about-us   |               1 |      0 |
|  3 | find-us    |               1 |      0 |
|  4 | contact-us |               1 |      2 |
|  5 | find-us    |               1 |      4 |
+----+------------+-----------------+--------+
```

I need a query to select the correct row in the table depending on what the slug name is. The problem is when slugs have the same name.

I have two possible paths, which a user can visit:

```
/find-us/
```

and

```
/about-us/contact-us/find-us/
```

I can think of one solution:

Which is to create an another column with the full paths:

```
full_path
--------
/portfolio/
/about-us/
/find-us/
/about-us/contact-us/
/about-us/contact-us/find-us/
```

But are there any kind of clever methods I can use to select the correct row. I am not sure if creating another column with full path names is such a great idea (because these have the potential to change), personally I would only like to use that as a last resort.

Thanks.

Comment: IIRC mysql does not allow recursive queries?

Comment: The full path is something that you have to know anyway to know which page you are serving right? So it seems like something that you probably do want to maintain, so for me the question would probably not be "do I want to maintain it?", but "how do I maintain it?", and I think that the correct answer to that is via a trigger.

Comment: Yes wildplasser, you are right recursive queries are not possible. B Tyler - That is an interesting thought and something I will consider.

Comment: The thing is, this is the kind of thing where you write occasionally and read often, so maintaining state is much better than doing some kind of funky hugely expensive query. Even if you could do recursive queries, it wouldn't be a good idea.

Comment: Using triggers will get nasty, because you have to chase the child nodes, too. In the OP's example: if 'potfolio'(id=1) changes, the fullpath for id={2,3,4,5} has to change, too. The same for 2-> {4,5}.

Comment: @wildplasser: Yep, that's kind of the point though isn't it; do the calculation once on write and have the fastest possible read. This provides the best user experience. Your recursive query will eventually calculate all those full paths; the difference is that you want to recalculate them over and over again in a complex way.

Comment: The recursive query does not perform worse than a fixed hierachy with a fixed number -say- 5 of levels. Given the possibility of recursion, a non-recursive solutions starts to look not-normalised, with redundant (functionally dependant) data in it. The query below does actually work, and it is elegant, IMHO. That mysql does not support it is a minor problem. Data-modelling should not depend on that kind of detail.

Comment: Yeah? You have two selects from the same table, a rather fancy cross join and a select distinct from the union and you are saying that performs identically to an indexed look-up on a single column that could be given a unique constraint? No chance. This is the kind of data that you want to and should cache. It's cute, but not clever.

Answer (score -1):

This would be possible if your DBMS supported recursive queries:

```
DROP SCHEMA tmp CASCADE;
CREATE SCHEMA tmp ;

CREATE TABLE tmp.webmeuk
    ( id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    , slug VARCHAR
    , content_type_id INTEGER NOT NULL
    , parent_id INTEGER REFERENCES tmp.webmeuk(id)
    );
INSERT INTO tmp.webmeuk( id , slug, content_type_id , parent_id )
VALUES(  0 , 'HTTP://pr0n.mysite.xx',    5 , NULL )
    , (  1 , 'portfolio',   5 , 0 )
    , (  2 , 'about-us',    1 , 0 )
    , (  3 , 'find-us',     1 , 0 )
    , (  4 , 'contact-us',  1 , 2 )
    , (  5 , 'find-us',     1 , 4 )
    ;

-- a room with a view
CREATE VIEW tmp.reteview AS (
    WITH RECURSIVE xx AS (
        SELECT w0.id AS id
        , w0.slug AS slug
        , w0.content_type_id AS content_type_id
        , w0.slug AS fullpath
        FROM tmp.webmeuk w0
        WHERE w0.parent_id IS NULL
      UNION 
        SELECT w1.id AS id
        , w1.slug AS slug
        , w1.content_type_id AS content_type_id
        , xx.fullpath || '/'::text || w1.slug AS fullpath
        FROM tmp.webmeuk w1, xx
        WHERE w1.parent_id = xx.id
        )
    SELECT * FROM xx
    );

SELECT * FROM tmp.reteview ;

-- Change one row of data
UPDATE tmp.webmeuk
SET slug = 'what-about-us'
WHERE id = 2;

SELECT * FROM tmp.reteview ;
```

Output:

```
NOTICE:  drop cascades to 2 other objects
DETAIL:  drop cascades to table tmp.webmeuk
drop cascades to view tmp.closure
DROP SCHEMA
CREATE SCHEMA
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "webmeuk_pkey" for table "webmeuk"
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 6
CREATE VIEW
 id |         slug          | content_type_id |                     fullpath                  
----+-----------------------+-----------------+---------------------------------------------------
  0 | HTTP://pr0n.mysite.xx |               5 | HTTP://pr0n.mysite.xx
  1 | portfolio             |               5 | HTTP://pr0n.mysite.xx/portfolio
  2 | about-us              |               1 | HTTP://pr0n.mysite.xx/about-us
  3 | find-us               |               1 | HTTP://pr0n.mysite.xx/find-us
  4 | contact-us            |               1 | HTTP://pr0n.mysite.xx/about-us/contact-us
  5 | find-us               |               1 | HTTP://pr0n.mysite.xx/about-us/contact-us/find-us
(6 rows)

UPDATE 1
 id |         slug          | content_type_id |                        fullpath                    
----+-----------------------+-----------------+--------------------------------------------------------
  0 | HTTP://pr0n.mysite.xx |               5 | HTTP://pr0n.mysite.xx
  1 | portfolio             |               5 | HTTP://pr0n.mysite.xx/portfolio
  3 | find-us               |               1 | HTTP://pr0n.mysite.xx/find-us
  2 | what-about-us         |               1 | HTTP://pr0n.mysite.xx/what-about-us
  4 | contact-us            |               1 | HTTP://pr0n.mysite.xx/what-about-us/contact-us
  5 | find-us               |               1 | HTTP://pr0n.mysite.xx/what-about-us/contact-us/find-us
(6 rows)
```