# Database designs -- a row referencing another row within same table

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, database-schema

I am currently designing a MySQL database that stores information pertaining to domains. Domain aliases belong to a domain, i.e. they have a parent, and so will reference a row from the same table in the **parent** field.

**domains**

```
id | name               | parent 
1  | bob.com            |  NULL
2  | bobcompetition.com |   1
```

The problem here is that I'm purposely defining null based records for non-alias domains and also referencing a row within the same table might cause difficulties.

How would you suggest I model this data?

```
domains « domain_aliases
```

might be one way to go but domain aliases **are** domains. Essentially all domains should sit in the *domains* table, but I need a way to reference one domain to its 'parent' or 'primary' domain.

Comment: Basically you want to store a collection of *trees* in a single database table...

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I found a nice article on this: http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Comment: I know that mysql does not support recursive queries, but if ti would something like this would serve your needs, IMHO. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7703199/mysql-query-indentiyfing-data-using-url-names-where-data-is-organised-into-a-h/7704118#7704118 Note: I don't want to start a platform war here, but your requirements seem to be in conflict.

Answer (score 2):

Well, how about:

Domains: ID, name

and

Aliases: ParentId, ChildId

(two foreign keys to the domains table)

This way all domains are in the domain table and you still have a way to find the relationship

Comment: And if you want to be closer to the original design, make the `Aliases.ChildId` unique.